# Node Js rest services using mongoclinet

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, distinct

I'm a junior developer and I'm developing a REST Service using Node JS, Express, MongoDB on Azure.
In my first rest service developed i always developed using Mongoose, but now i have seen there is some problem using mongoose on Cosmos DB.
Cosmos DB connection Node js work with MongoDb mongoclient. I have create a db.js file:

```
var mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://dbname:xxxxxxxx@dbname.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true", function (err, db) {
db.close();
});

module.exports = mongoClient;
```

and i have define a model:

```
var mongoClient = require('../config/db.js');


var ProfileSchema = mongoClient.Schema({
companyName: { type: String, required: true },
firstname: {type: String, required: true},
address: {type: String, required: true},
city: {type: String, required: true},
state: {type: String, required: false},
postalcode: {type: String, required: true},
country: {type: String, required: true},
telephone: {type: String, required: true},
email: {type: String, required: true}
});
mongoClient.model('Profile', ProfileSchema);

module.exports = mongoClient.model('Profile');
```

ad this is my router:

```
var Profile = require('../models/Profile');


router.get('/profile', function(req,res){
Profile.find({}, (err, profile) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).send({ status: 'ko', data: {msg: err.message }});
    }
    res.status(200).send({status: 'ok', data: {msg: 'List', profile: profile}});
});
});
```

Now when i tried to run app ai receive this error:
mongoClient.Schema is not a function
I don't know if my code it's ok?
How i can fix?

Thanks
Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing concepts. 
What you are trying to do is to create a MongoDB Schema using MongoClient, which does not support this.
Use Mongoose for that:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

MongoClient is a basic driver for MongoDB and I don't think you want to use it directly.

Also, in your model file you are using this:

```
var mongoClient = require('../config/db.js');
```

and I don't know what you have in the file db.js but I don't think you implemented a custom Schema() function there, that's why you are getting the error "mongoClient.Schema is not a function".
To make this works, avoid using MongoClient directly and check out some tutorials for Mongoose.